# JavaScript (Dojo) XHR - encode special characters

Tags: javascript, .net, dojo, xmlhttprequest, character

I'm posting my form via JavaScript (Dojo) XHR. Everything works fine except when I wish to post any special characters. For example XHR tags:

```
<someTag>
```

I get error 500 (internal error). How can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like your error is at the server-side, not JS.

Comment: No, I'm working in .NET, set up a break point and it doesn't even come in. If i post "normal text" (for example "someTag" withouth < and >) it works.

Comment: What kind of special characters? What is the exact code you're using? As you already said so yourself; it's an internal *server* error. Probably nothing wrong with your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your server-side code is interpreting the posted values as code instead of a string. I would need an example of your server side code to improve that but on the client side you could use:

```
var escapedValue = escape("<someTag>");
```

Note that it **is not, I repeat, NOT** safe to rely on client side character encoding. You should fix this issue on the server side.

Comment: Client already encodes < into %3C which is correct. It just doesn't come to the server. How can I fix this on the server?

Comment: Like I said, I would need an example of your server-side code before I'm able to help you improve that code.

Comment: For example: public ActionResult ViaXhr(string test)
{
    int x = 1;
}